# Android Lollipop -- connect to Wifi and Cellular at the same time?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

I've heard that Android 5.0 (Lollipop) supports the ability to connect to your Wifi and Cellular networks simultaneously, so I could connect to a private Wifi network (e.g. my GoPro camera) while remaining connected to the Internet via the cellular connection.

Is this accurate, if so where can I find more information on this feature?

Comment: I'm confused by this question.  I am able to connect to wifi and cellular connection at the same time now, without 5.0.

Comment: Uhh, I don't think this is true. I actually wanted to ask from where did you hear about this, but since you asked where can you find more info, I doubt you could provide more info :(

Comment: @New-To-IT WiFi & **mobile network** at the same time? Are you using custom ROM? Because I can't, with Nexus 4 since stock JellyBean until now (stock Lollipop).

Comment: They're both connected as I speak!  No custom ROM, just stock Android!

Comment: @New-To-IT interesting... so you can set which apps use WiFi and which apps use mobile data? You could try to answer this question then, since I never know about this. **Edit**: perhaps it's a specific vendor feature, as it seems [Samsung Galaxy](http://androidforums.com/threads/wifi-and-mobile-data-at-the-same-time.746714/) has it.